# shell script to find multiple strings in multiple files and then them like "string - filename"

Tags: shell, solaris

I want to write a shell script which takes input from a file and search for that string in multiple file in a directory. I have successfully written a script which shows filename contains matched string. but I want to print the input string name also.

input.txt -

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

dir - `/a/b/`

output -

```
name1 : file1, file2
name2 : file1
name3 : no results found
name4 : file4
```

Comment: Sounds useful. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `grep -F -f file files ...` maybe `-o` as well.

Comment: I tried - find dirname -exec egrep -n -f inputfile '{}' \; -print

Answer (score 0):

Many amenities that are taken for granted on Linux are not available on Solaris (at least Solaris 10 and older).  For example, the `grep` commands do not take the `-r` option, and `find` does not support `+` instead of `;`.  This makes life fiddlier.

I am going to assume that your file names (and the searched-for names) do not contain spaces or newlines (or other characters that cause trouble).  I'm also going to assume you use `ksh` or `bash` and not `/bin/sh` so that it is feasible to use `$(...)` instead of having to use back-ticks.

There are three parts to your requirement:

1. Read a list of names to be searched for.
2. Find the files containing those names.
3. Format the results of finding the files.

This can be tackled with:

```
base="/a/b"
while read name
do
    list=$(find "$base" -type f -print | xargs grep -l "$name")
    if [ -z "$list" ]
    then echo "$name : no results found"
    else { echo "$name"
           echo "$list"
         } | awk 'NR == 1 { printf "%s : ", $1; next }
                          { printf "%s%s", pad, $1; pad = ", " }
                  END     { printf "\n" }'
    fi
done < input.txt
```

If you want cleverer formatting (removing the prefix path in `$base`, for example) or splitting long lines, you can add that.  I'd do prefix removal in a `sed` script processing the output of `echo "$list"`; cleverer formatting would require a more complex `awk` script.

Tested with `bash` etc on Mac OS X 10.7.5 — not Solaris.  Given the file name assumptions, the only mild cause for concern, though, is the use of `next` in the `awk` script.  There are ways to work around that if necessary, but the alternative script isn't as clean as the version above (though it isn't horrendously worse).

Comment: Thanks Jon, This solved my purpose. I am ok with the format so no need for awk script.